# Pulling images from a hosting company to django project

Tags: django, static, django-staticfiles

I have recently put my website into production. I am using a company to host my projects on their servers and everything is working perfectly apart from when I upload images.

The uploading its self works and they are uploaded to the base/static/images/images folder correctly. But the website its self when uploading through django admin are trying to pull the images from the public_html/images/images folder. What would I need to change for either the images to be pulled from correct folder or images to be uploaded to correct folder. Below is my settings for my static files.

```
    STATIC_URL = 'static/'
    MEDIA_URL = 'images/'
    
    STATICFILES_DIRS = [
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
    ]
    
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/images')
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try placing this in your main urls.py file:

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import static
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

urlpatterns = [

]

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Nope nothing unfortunately, Maybe as its the uploading that is the issue its down to the hosting company to sort out.

Comment: Try restarting the server.

Comment: Also try performing an upload through the admin and then check the access logs to see where exactly it's posting to.